# Different R-squared by plm within regression and fixest?

Tags: r, plm, fixest

I am running a FE regression of firm characteristics on the dependant variable effective tax rates.
I tried both plm package and fixest package. I understand the differences in the standard errors (and I correct them with coeftest for the plm regression, not shown here), however I do not understand the difference in *adjusted* R-squared between fixest and plm.
Coefficients are the same in both models, so adjusted R-squared should be the same, right?

````
> fe <- feols(GETR ~ SIZE + LEV + CAPINT + INVINT + ROA + LLEV + CF + EK| id + year,data = panel52,cluster = ~ id+year)
> summary(fe)
OLS estimation, Dep. Var.: GETR
Observations: 19,240 
Fixed-effects: id: 1,924,  year: 10
Standard-errors: Clustered (id & year) 
        Estimate Std. Error   t value  Pr(>|t|)    
SIZE    0.031979   0.010624  3.010150 0.0147123 *  
LEV    -0.021880   0.033039 -0.662243 0.5244090    
CAPINT  0.098979   0.027374  3.615754 0.0056088 ** 
INVINT  0.045080   0.039294  1.147250 0.2808605    
ROA     0.222094   0.089892  2.470664 0.0355315 *  
LLEV    0.015973   0.025740  0.620558 0.5502796    
CF     -0.237174   0.098485 -2.408230 0.0393631 *  
EK      0.027064   0.063651  0.425196 0.6806793    
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
RMSE: 0.160357     Adj. R2: 0.212174
                 Within R2: 0.004764
> summary(fe52)
Twoways effects Within Model

Call:
plm(formula = GETR ~ SIZE + LEV + CAPINT + INVINT + ROA + LLEV + 
    CF + EK, data = panel52, na.action = na.exclude, effect = "twoways", 
    model = "within")

Balanced Panel: n = 1924, T = 10, N = 19240

Residuals:
      Min.    1st Qu.     Median    3rd Qu.       Max. 
-0.7032714 -0.0635238 -0.0079128  0.0376269  0.9293129 

Coefficients:
         Estimate Std. Error t-value  Pr(>|t|)    
SIZE    0.0319790  0.0065342  4.8941 9.967e-07 ***
LEV    -0.0218800  0.0356996 -0.6129    0.5400    
CAPINT  0.0989786  0.0222388  4.4507 8.612e-06 ***
INVINT  0.0450804  0.0366761  1.2292    0.2190    
ROA     0.2220941  0.0389295  5.7050 1.182e-08 ***
LLEV    0.0159730  0.0180534  0.8848    0.3763    
CF     -0.2371736  0.0425711 -5.5712 2.567e-08 ***
EK      0.0270641  0.0380943  0.7104    0.4774    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Total Sum of Squares:    497.11
Residual Sum of Squares: 494.74
R-Squared:      0.004764
Adj. R-Squared: -0.10685
F-statistic: 10.3509 on 8 and 17299 DF, p-value: 1.4467e-14```
````

Comment: If you check the `?fixest::r2` help page you'll see it offers several aternatives. For example, should the fixed effects count as "explaining variance", or not? This may  help you understand which statistic is being offered.

Comment: Sorry, if I don't understand what you mean. I think I understand the adjusted R2 in fixest. The plm only seems to display the within R2. Can I change this to the similar R2 as in fixest?

Comment: I dunno, but maybe the plm package documentation will tell you. Try `?plm::r.squared`.